# Redirecting a list of folders with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I recovered a project but it is not generic at all. I looked a bit what was on .htaccess but it is not obvious. So I ask you, you will probably have the solution!

Currently my *.htaccess* file is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exemple.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exemple.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule folderA/(.+) www/$1
RewriteRule folderB/(.+) www/$1
```

with copy of *index.php* files in **folderA/index.php** and **folderB/index.php**.

*index.php* are :

```
<?php
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

I want the http://exemple/folderA/ , http://exemple/folderB/, http://exemple/folderC/ ... to be written and displayed in the browser but redirects to *www/index.php*

Commonly new folders are added by the old team. I would like to have the same behavior without the folders that multiply.

Can you help me ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I used was something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !www/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folderA 
RewriteRule (.*) /www/index.php [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !www/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folderB 
RewriteRule (.*) /www/index.php [L]
```

This is a quick-n-dirty approach, that I used on a project recently because out glorious admins think that all code would be in the document root :(

Also, I have no idea whether it will work for you, and you probably could collapse those rules into one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately when I fill in the url http://localhost/folderA/, the browser tells me Not Found

The requested URL /www/folderA/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Work well, Big thanks! After that it may be too much to ask, but is it possible to make it even more generic with a list of folders in another file? Like folderList.ini who contains names of each folder ? Anyway, still a great thank you

Comment: It **should be** something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folderA|folderB|folderC`